# Reading txt file into a single column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to load a book into a single column dataframe so I can run a word count.

```py
df = pd.read_table('dataframe/War_and_Peace.txt', header=None, sep=" ", on_bad_lines='skip')
```

I tried `sep="delimiter"` and it breaks it down to one sentence at a time.

When I try to manually adjust the first two lines, it starts skipping chunks of the text file. Any thoughts?

[Wordcount dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUpcT.png)

Comment: I would not do that with pandas, but something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011521/count-frequency-of-word-in-text-file-in-python

Comment: after you get the word frequency `dictionary` you may convert it to a dataframe like `pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(dictionary).rename('count').rename_axis('word')`, if the dictionary's keys are words and the corresponding values are counts of the words.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that and keep you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend textblob for text recognition.